# Can't create users programmatically in a wordpress environment

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm new to wordpress and I'm looking forward to adding users through a front-end register page, I'm really confused right now ecause I cant get this code to work, it just wont create the user.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Register
*/

get_header(); ?>



<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
    $pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

    if($email1 == $email2){
        if($pass1 == $pass2)
        {
            if( null == username_exists( $email_address ) ) {
                $user_login = $_POST['uname'];
                $user_email = $_POST['email1'];
                $user_pass = $_POST['pass1'];

              $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_login, $user_pass, $user_email );

              wp_update_user(
                array(
                  'ID'          =>    $user_id,
                  'nickname'    =>    $email_address
                )
              );
              $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
              $user->set_role( 'contributor' );
            }


        }else{
            echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match <br/>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Sorry your Emails dont match <br/>";
        exit();
    }

}else{
    $form = <<<EOT
    <form action="" method="POST">
        First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/> <br/>
        Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname"/> <br/>
        Username:   <input type="text" name="uname"/> <br/>
        Email:  <input type="text" nam="email1"/> <br/>
        Confim Email:   <input type="text" name="email2"/> <br/>
        Password:   <input type="password" name="pass1"/> <br/>
        Confirm Password:   <input type="password" name="pass2"/> <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"/>
    </form>
EOT;

echo $form;
}

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks.

Not sure if important or not, but I chose wpwpp_ as the prefix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your function
     if( null == username_exists( $email_address ) ) //$email_addrress should be either $email1 or $email2

But i would recomend the wp_insert_user rather than wp_create_user instead..

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Register
*/

get_header(); ?>



<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1'];
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2'];

if($email1 == $email2){
    if($pass1 == $pass2)
    {
        if( null == username_exists( $email1) ) {
            $user_login = $_POST['uname'];
            $user_email = $_POST['email1'];
            $user_pass = $_POST['pass1'];

$userdata = array(
'user_login'    =>  $user_login ,
'user_pass'=> $user_pass,
'user_email'=>$user_email
);

$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

         wp_update_user(
            array(
              'ID'          =>    $user_id,
              'nickname'    =>    $email_address
            )
          );
          $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
          $user->set_role( 'contributor' );
        }


    }else{
        echo "Sorry, your passwords do not match <br/>";
    }
}else{
    echo "Sorry your Emails dont match <br/>";
    exit();
}

}else{
$form = <<<EOT
<form action="" method="POST">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="name"/> <br/>
    Last Name:  <input type="text" name="lname"/> <br/>
    Username:   <input type="text" name="uname"/> <br/>
    Email:  <input type="text" nam="email1"/> <br/>
    Confim Email:   <input type="text" name="email2"/> <br/>
    Password:   <input type="password" name="pass1"/> <br/>
    Confirm Password:   <input type="password" name="pass2"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit"/>
</form>
EOT;

echo $form;
}

?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This might work for you !! Good luck

Comment: It still won't work and it keeps sending me to "Page not found", only when I press Submit with no fields covered is when it sends me to whatever I put in action=""

Comment: i assume you want to redirect the user to your homepage after registration.. so you might use the wp_redirect() after the closing of the 
.....
else{ echo "sorry your emails dont mathch...";
exit();}
wp_redirect('your_site_url');
}
........

Answer (score 1):

You never ever define `$email_address`:

```
$email1 = $_POST['email1'];
$email2 = $_POST['email2'];
```

So when you do this:

```
        if( null == username_exists( $email_address ) ) {
```

you're essentially doing `username_exists(null)` and always get back "yep, that user doesn't exist".